# Use TPU in Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tpu

I am currently training a neural network with the help of a TPU.
I changed the runtime type and initialized the TPU.
I have the feeling that it is still not faster. I used https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tpu.
Did I something wrong?

```
# TPU initialization
resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu='grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'])
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)
# This is the TPU initialization code that has to be at the beginning.
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
print("All devices: ", tf.config.list_logical_devices('TPU'))

.
.
.
# experimental_steps_per_execution = 50
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=learning_rate), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], experimental_steps_per_execution = 50)
```

The summary of my model

[image]

Is there anything I still have to consider or adjust?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create TPU strategy:

```
strategy = tf.distribute.TPUStrategy(resolver).
```

And than use this strategy properly:

```
with strategy.scope():
  model = create_model()
  model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer! And how do I create the TPU strategy? May you have a Code snippet?

Comment: how do you handle this error `ResourceExhaustedError: 9 root error(s) found.
  (0) Resource exhausted: {{function_node __inference_train_function_14917}} Compilation failure: Ran out of memory in memory space hbm. Used 8.29G of 7.48G hbm. Exceeded hbm capacity by 825.64M.` ?

Comment: your model is huge. Try to decrease batch_size to 8

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. I tried batch_size = 8. Unfortunately, the error keeps recurring.

Comment: try batch_size = 1

Comment: you have no choice other than simplifying your model :(